# Downloading OS when computer has been stripped

Tags: downloads

i have 6 laptops - 3 Dell Vostro 1500s and 3 HP Compaq NC 8430, their operating systems were removed and we need to load one to get a lab set up at deaf school in Africa. How do I get the software to load? Can I make a disk? They are 64 bit processors.

Comment: Do you have a working computer that you can use to download the Ubuntu Live software?  http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Comment: No, you will need a computer with a working OS (Can be Windows, OSX, Ubuntu), in order to download Ubuntu and write it to a DVD or USB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 5):

You will need to download a Ubuntu ISO file from here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and burn it to ether a **USB** drive or **DVD** you can use this guide to burn your ISO image http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

You will probably need to go in to your **BIOS** and configure your machine to boot from the **USB or DVD**.Then insert the USB into your machine and hit F12 to select the USB device

Just follow the directions you will then be able to try Ubuntu even before you can install it. I would try it just to make sure it's the OS you want and see how it preforms

Comment: I did all that - selected boot from USB, turned computer off and put in flash drive and restarted but it has not worked and since there is nothing on the screen except flashing cursor, not sure what to do now. Is there anything else I need to do?